# Ruby rescue and best practice syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, rescue

I had some code that looked similar to this:

```
foo = SomeActiveRecordModel.where(bar: 10).first.foo rescue ''
```

Once I started using Rubocop it was yelling at me for the rescue syntax there. So I figured there were at least two other ways to write this code them being:

```
foo = 
begin
  foo = SomeActiveRecordModel.where(bar: 10).first.foo
rescue NoMethodError
  ''
end
```

And:

```
foo = SomeActiveRecordModel.where(bar: 10).first
foo.present? ? foo.foo : ''
```

Which of these ways would be preferred, or is there an alternative way that is preferred?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you using this?  I see all three answers combined to be outstanding.  But if  you're using this in a controller, perhaps moving the `where` method call to a `scope` or `class method` in `SomeActiveRecordModel` might be nicer.

Comment: This is being used in a class method. It's being used to grab any rules that exist from the database and applying those rules to a sql query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual rule of thumb is that exceptions should be reserved for exceptional circumstances, those that you don't expect in the normal flow of control. For one thing, they're usually slower than the alternatives.

Here's what I prefer for your scenario:

```
foo = SomeActiveRecordModel.find_by_bar(10).try(:foo) || ''
```

Comment: Or even `SomeActiveRecordModel.find_by(bar: 10).try(:foo) || ''` or perhaps `SomeActiveRecordModel.find_by(bar: 10).try(:foo).to_s` as `foo` is presumably a string.

Comment: I had seen syntax like this before but that didn't even cross my mind to try. Thanks for your answer and the time you spend describing it.

Answer (score 9):

Exception handling is for, well, handling *exceptional* situations. Clearly, sometimes a record may not be there. Handling it with catching `NoMethodError` is absolutely the wrong way to do it. For one thing, it will not only catch "no method foo on nil:NilClass", but all the other "no method" errors, which may happen (typo somewhere, etc).

So, "record not found" being a non-exceptional situtation, you have to handle it as such, with a conditional of some sort.

```
foo = SomeActiveRecordModel.where(bar: 10).first
return '' unless foo
foo.bar
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for taking the time to educate me on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

From now on, neither will be the preferred way. The preferred way would be:

```
foo = SomeActiveRecordModel.where(bar: 10).first&.foo || ""
```

Comment: I feel that this new operator will be much abused. :)

Comment: Whoa, whoa, when did this happen? And *why*?

Comment: @zetetic: [ruby 2.3](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-2-3-features/). Because reasons.

Comment: This is pretty nifty. Just looking at it I would have expected it to throw an error if foo doesn't exist, but I guess it doesn't! Thanks for your answer/time!